# Updating two tables, retrieving Foreign Key

Tags: coldfusion, foreign-keys

I am inserting data into two tables, however I can not figure out (after hours of Googling) how to insert data into the second table after retrieving the new ID created after the first update?
I'm using `<CFINSERT>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<CFQUERY result="result_name">` and the new ID will be available at `result_name.generatedkey` ..  `<cfinsert>` and `<cfupdate>`, while easy and fast for simple jobs, they are pretty limited.

Comment: So using <CFUPDATE> to insert the first round of values, followed by the <CFQUERY> to retrieve the new ID, followed by the second <CFUPDATE>?

Comment: Thanks, I got the error: Attribute validation error for tag CFQUERY? When using the above?

Comment: nope, forget about `<cfupdate>`, use `<cfquery>` and `<cfqueryparam>` to form your own Insert statement.  Once the insert is done, you can fetch the new ID from `result_name.generatedkey` and then update/insert on the next `<cfquery>`.  Learn how to use cfquery here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html

Comment: Sorry! So if I used: <cfquery name="myResult" datasource="XXX"> </cfquery> What would go in the middle?

Comment: I have those bits....its drawing the primary key that has just been inserted back out?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e02b-7ff3.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e02b-7ffc

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5996/discussion-between-henry-and-ez87)

Comment: @ez87 - Take a look at henry's example again. I think you are conusing `result` with the cfquery `name`. (They are not the same thing).

Comment: Darn typos. That should be *confusing* "result" with "name".

Comment: Thanks everyone, ive tried using the above but get an error saying 'Attribute validation error for tag CFQUERY'? Any ideas?

Comment: IIRC, the `result` attribute was introduced in CF8. What is your version?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used cfinsert myself, but this blog post from Ben Forta says you may not be able to use cfinsert if you need a generated key http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2006/10/3/Use-CFINSERT-And-CFUPDATE

Yes, I realize that blog post is old, but it doesn't appear much has changed.

Why not use a traditional INSERT statement wrapped in a `<cfquery>` tag?

Comment: Thank you! I have re structured the query and have both updates for table 1 and 2 in separate <CFQUERY> tags. I also have: <cfquery name="myResult" datasource="XXX"> </cfquery> What would go in the middle to draw the last primary key out?